# GWT: Putting raw HTML inside a Label

Tags: java, gwt

Is there a way to put raw HTML inside of a `Label` widget with GWT?  The constructor and `setText()` methods automatically escape the text for HTML (so `<` appears as `&lt;`, etc).

What I need is something like:

```
String matched = "two";
List<String> values = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String v : values){
  if (v.equals(matched)){
    sb.append("<b>" + v + "<b>");
  } else {
    sb.append(v);
  }
  sb.append(", ");
}
Label label = new Label();
label.setRawText(sb.toString());
//div contains the following HTML: "one, <b>two</b>, three, "
```

I want to output a comma-separated list of Strings, but I want one of those Strings to be bolded.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, I'm going to answer my own question because I found what I was looking for.

The `SafeHtmlBuilder` class is perfect for this.  You tell it what strings you want to escape and what strings you do not want to escape.  It works like `StringBuilder` because you call `append` methods:

```
String matched = "two";
List<String> values = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three <escape-me>");
SafeHtmlBuilder builder = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
for (String v : values){
  if (v.equals(matched)){
    builder.appendHtmlConstant("<b>");
    builder.appendEscaped(v);
    builder.appendHtmlConstant("</b>");
  } else {
    builder.appendEscaped(v);
  }
  builder.appendEscaped(", ");
}
HTML widget = new HTML();
widget.setHTML(builder.toSafeHtml());
//div contains the following HTML: "one, <b>two</b>, three &lt;escape-me&gt;, "
```

Note that the `appendHtmlConstant` method expects a **complete** tag.  So if you want to add attributes to the tag whose values change during runtime, it won't work.  For example, this **won't** work (it throws an `IllegalArgumentException`):

```
String url = //...
SafeHtmlBuilder builder = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
builder.appendHtmlConstant("<a href=\""); //throws IllegalArgumentException
builder.appendEscaped(url);
builder.appendHtmlConstant("\">link</a>");
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the HTML class (Or more likely: The InlineHTML class instead of the Label class. InlineHTML works like label, except that you can give it html.

And just a security warning: if part of the input to your InlineHTML object is input by the user, remember to strip html out of that part, so users can't insert their own scripts into your code.

Comment: Label ↔ HTML, InlineLabel ↔ InlineHTML. Formers are `div`s, latters `span`s.

Comment: How would I escape the parts that come from the user, but *not* escape the `<b>` tag?  Please see my edited question with updated code sample--what should I do for the "htmlEscape" method?

Answer (score 3):

Either create a label and set it to bold:

```
Label label = new Label("text");
label.getElement().getStyle().setFontWeight(FontWeight.BOLD);
```

Or you can create a `SpanElement` and set its innerHtml.

Comment: But I want to bold only *part* of the label text.  Can I use `SpanElement` to do that?

Comment: `SpanElement` will not escape your text. Just call `SpanElement#setInnerHTML`

Comment: What if I want to escape part of the text, but leave the `<b>` tags untouched? (see updated code sample in question)  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's example to put a space in a widget, e.g. Label:

```
public void setTextNbsp( final Widget w ) { 
    w.getElement().setInnerHTML( "&nbsp;" );
}
```

Other HTML entities could be used as well.  Take care with this not to open security holes.  SafeHtml, etc. might need consideration if doing something more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use SpanElement where you don't want the html to be escaped and label where you want then to be escaped and put them on a vertical panel so that they would appear as a single line of text.

Comment: That seems overkill to me.  Is there any other way?