# How to insert <b> Element in GWT Label

Tags: java, html, gwt

I'm using GWT UiBinder and I want to create the following Label

*--------------------------------------------*

You can upload only **.jpg** images

*--------------------------------------------*

```
<g:Label ui:field="imgInfo">You can upload only <b>.jpg</b> images</g:Label>
```

But of course it is incorrect example. I want to use Label, because I want to add PopupPanel

```
 final PopupPanel popupImgInfo = new PopupInfo("Max size of the imagde:10Mb");

 @UiHandler("imgInfo")
    void doProtocol(MouseOverEvent event) {
        popupImgInfo
                .setPopupPositionAndShow(new PopupPanel.PositionCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {
                        int left = imgInfo.getAbsoluteLeft();
                        int top = imgInfo.getAbsoluteTop() - 120;
                        popupImgInfo.setPopupPosition(left, top);
                        popupImgInfo.setWidth("400px");
                    }
                });
    }

    @UiHandler("imgInfo")
    void doProtocolHide(MouseOutEvent event) {
        popupImgInfo.hide();
    }
```

So my problem is how to insert html Element in Label or you can provide other solutions to make text bold in GWT Label.

Comment: yourLabel.getElement().setInnerHTML("You can upload only <b>.jpg</b> images");

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT: Putting raw HTML inside a Label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692306/gwt-putting-raw-html-inside-a-label)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [HTML](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTML.html) widget instead of a Label one:

```
<g:HTML ui:field="imgInfo">You can upload only <b>.jpg</b> images</g:HTML>
```

Comment: If you want inline labels (as it seems the default), `InlineHTML` might be a better fit as it produces a `<span>` tag, not `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

philfr49 is absolutelly right. Label use *createTextNode*, and you can't use HTML. If you still want to do it you can do this:

```
DirectionalTextHelper directionalTextHelper = new DirectionalTextHelper(imgInfo.getElement(), true);
directionalTextHelper.setTextOrHtml("You can upload only <b>.jpg</b>; images", true);
```

Update:
Both HTML(class="gwt-HTML") and Label(class="gwt-Label") produce DIV element as wrapper element. Both classes are empty in standard.css. So just make your choice which method suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using `SafeHtmlBuilder` class. You tell it what strings you want to escape and what strings you do not want to escape. It works like `StringBuilder` because you call append methods.

Please refer to link for similar answer:
[GWT: Putting raw HTML inside a Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692306/gwt-putting-raw-html-inside-a-label)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DOM Element instead.

```
@UiField
Element myLabel;

public void setLabelText(String text)
{
    myLabel.setInnerHTML(new SafeHtmlBuilder().appendEscaped(text).toSafeHtml().asString());
}
```